# Shift fails in Zsh: "shift count must be <= $#"

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have a bash script which contains `shift` command.

It runs ok in bash, but in zsh environment, `shift` command seems different.

## zsh

```
$ shift
shift: shift count must be <= $#
```

## bash

```
$ shift

# OK here
```

Is `shift` command not compatible with `zsh` and `bash`? How can I make the script run in `zsh`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both shells consider it an error when the argument to `shift` is greater than the number of positional parameters (i.e. `$#`).

Since `shift` without an argument is virtually the same as `shift 1`, when there are no positional parameters, it causes an error and returns a non-zero exit value.

The only difference is that **zsh** prints an error message when that happens, and **bash** does not.

## bash

```
$ set --
$ shift
$ echo $?
1
```

## zsh

```
$ set --
$ shift
shift: shift count must be <= $#
$ echo $?
1
```